# validate textfield onkeypress event in firefox JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp, firefox, onkeypress

I have written onKeyPress event which validates text when user enters some text and then tabs out from some field should validate text and if nothing is entered or incorrect value is entered, should give error to inform user and focus should back to the field and user must not be allowed to next field other than help button for field.

```
<jade:input type="text" name="dtxtDesigCd" 
    value="" size="10" maxlength="8" 
    classname="input" disabledclass="disabled-input" style="color: black"  
    datasource="dsDesigHourDetail:desigCode"
    onkeypress= "checkDesignation(this, event);">
</jade:input>
```

I also have a custom JSP tag "PickList" which is basically a button which display
a modal window with help from database for related field and selected record from database is displayed into the textfields in JSP after selection from help window.

Modified SOFIA Framework was used by our earlier vendor and now I have to maintain the code. The problem with earlier code was this button had to be double clicked for getting help as it used onblur instead of onkeypress and that too multiple tries were required as it kept giving error.

Earlier code with onblur was

```
    onblur="setValue('DESIGNATION');" onkeyup="capitalize(this);"
```

which has now been replaced with

```
    onkeypress= "checkDesignation(this, event);">
```

The code for help button / PickList in JSP is as follows:

```
<rap:pickfromlist name="picklistDesignation" datasource="dsDesigHourDetail" 
    pflheading="Designation Details" focusfield="dtxtDesigCd"
    pflcolumnsdesc="Designation Code, Description" 
    fieldlist="distinct emp_desig_cd, emp_desig_desc " 
    lookuptable="pmm_designation" orderby="emp_desig_cd"
    targetproperty="desigCode, designation" 
    whereclause=" executive_post='N' and crew_flg = 'N'" />
```

In this field, the description for designation is captured as picked from picklist or after form is submitted through setValue method which sends value passed to server through hidden variable action in the form and form is submitted.

```
<jade:input type="text" name="dlblDesigDesc" value="" size="50" 
    classname="labeltext" style="color: black" 
    datasource="dsDesigHourDetail:designation" enabled="False">
</jade:input>
```

checkDesignation(obj, evt) is defined as

```
function checkDesignation(obj, evt) {
    var evt = (evt) ? evt : (window.event) ? event : null;
    if (evt) {
        var len = TrimString(obj.value).length;
        alert("Designation : " + obj.value);
        if (evt.keyCode == 9 && len >= 0) {
            if (len == 0) {
                setErrMessage('Designation must be entered and not blank');
                document.forms[0].htmlPageTopContainer_pageForm_detailDesigHourForm_dtxtDesigCd.focus();
                document.forms[0].htmlPageTopContainer_pageForm_detailDesigHourForm_dtxtDesigCd.value = '';
                setValue('DESIGNATION');
                return false;
            } else {
                capitalize(obj);
                setValue('DESIGNATION');
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You made a very nice decription. Now what is the precise question?

Answer (score 1):

check this

```
    $("#textbox").bind("onKeyPress ", function (e) {
                if (e.altKey || e.ctrlKey || e.shiftKey){
                    return true;
    }
    else{
    // you have this text box inner text in this.val() and can be checked with 
           your validate function.
    }
            });
```